# ASP.net Core - Linq - Dynamic query inside foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Candidats have a string field with some zipcode where they are able to work, separated by comma (30,34,66).

We have a functionnality where my client can search for candidat matching the mission. There is a field of many zipcode where my client want to search (34,75) for exemple.

So i use Linq for filter the candidat and i need candidat who are matching 34 OR 75.

How can i do that ?

```
foreach(var dep in ListeDepartementRecherche)
{
 pListeCandidatRecherche = pListeCandidatRecherche.Where(c => 
 c.DepartementMobiliteCandidat.Contains(dep));
}
```

This code return candidat who match 34 AND 75

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `String.Split(....)` and `Contains` trim and parse if needed

Comment: Reverse the `Contains`: `dep.Contains(c.DepartementMobiliteCandidat)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code that you have, variable is overriding in the first iteration which will give you the wrong results.

You can use the below LINQ to achieve the expected behavior (i.e. OR)

```
pListeCandidatRecherche.Where(c => 
      ListeDepartementRecherche
           .Any(x => ("," + c.DepartementMobiliteCandidat + ",").Contains("," + x + ",")));
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, i needed to edit a little bit the code, there is a complete solution working for my case :

.Where(c => ListeDepartementRecherche.Any(x => c.DepartementMobiliteCandidat.Split(',').AsEnumerable().Contains(x)))